# How to access values of cells within a row of a table which has been checked by a checkbox in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, html-table

I was wondering if anyone could help me with getting this working.

I'm using HTML to create a table which has at least 1 row but no max number of rows - as they can be added/removed by the user - and 4 columns, 1st contains a checkbox and the last 2 contain drop down menus.

I wish to be able to store the values of those menus in an array only if that row's checkbox has been checked. e.g if the first row has 1 and A as it's dropdown values and the second row has 2 and B. If only row 1 has been checked the array should only contain [1,A]. Instead mine holds all the values including the non-checked ones i.e [1,A,2,B].

My code for Javascript function and html table are below:

```js
function calculate(textID) {
  var table = document.getElementById('course'); //id of table
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var array = []; //array to hold the values
  var c = 0;

  dmenus = document.getElementByTagName("select"); //get the drop down menus

  for (var a = 1; a < rowCount; i++) { //a = 1 as the 1st row contains column headings
    var row = table.rows[a];
    var check = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if (null != check && true == check.checked) {
      for (var b = 0; b < dmenus.length; b++) {
        val = dmenus[b].options[dmenus[b].selectedIndex].value;
        array[c] = val; //set index of array to equal value of dropdown box
        c++;
      }
    } else {
      b++;
    }
  }
```

```html
<table id="course">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ucheck" id="ucheck" onclick="checkAll('course')" /></td>
    <th style="color:white">Course Title</th>
    <th style="color:white">Credits</th>
    <th style="color:white">Grade</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="tick" id="tick" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td>
      <select name="credits" id="credits">
                    <option...</select></td>
    <td>
      <select name="grade" id="grade">
                    <option...</td>
 </table>
```

It works only for the first row but if there are more than 1 row it doesn't do what it's supposed to. The coding platform I'm working on does not seem to support JQuery so Javascript code will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work, rearranged the code a little bit. There's probably a more efficient way of doing it, but hey it works for me :D

```js
var array = [];
var narray = [];
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;

ddownselects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");

//get all elements into one array
for (var j = 0; j < ddownselects.length; j++) {
  val = ddownselects[j].options[els[j].selectedIndex].value;
  array[a] = val;
  a++;
}

var rlen = array.length / 2; //number of rows
for (var i = 1; i <= rlen; i++) {
  var row = table.rows[i];
  var check = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
  if (check.checked) {
    narray[b] = array[c]; //set array values to new array only if that row is checked
    b++;
    c++;
    narray[b] = array[c];
    b++;
    c++;
  } else {
    c += 2; //if not checked, got to next row's values
  }
```

```html
<table id="course">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ucheck" id="ucheck" onclick="checkAll('course')" /></td>
    <th style="color:white">Course Title</th>
    <th style="color:white">Credits</th>
    <th style="color:white">Grade</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="tick" id="tick" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td>
      <select name="credits" id="credits">
                    <option...</select></td>
    <td>
      <select name="grade" id="grade">
                    <option...</td>
```